# Attached Property binding in KeyBinding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have a problem with binding in KeyBinding in WPF. I'm developing .net 3.5 project using WPF with MVVM pattern. I have to fire command whenever some letter will be typed. Unfortunately Command and CommandParameter aren't Dependency Properties in this .net version and i can't bind to them. So I've written attached properties to assign command and command parameter from my view model. But binding to them isn't working, when I change binding to text (in command parameter) CommandBindingParameterChanged will rise but it doesn't when there is binding to parameter. I tired to set window's name and pass that to binding but it also didn't work. But when I'll assign the same command to button it works fine. Here is my code snippet:

Attached properties:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandBindingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandBinding", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Helper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, CommandChanged));

    public static ICommand GetCommandBinding(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (ICommand)o.GetValue(CommandBindingProperty);
    }
    public static void SetCommandBinding(DependencyObject o, ICommand value)
    {
        o.SetValue(CommandBindingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var input = d as InputBinding;

        input.Command = (ICommand)e.NewValue;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandBindingParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandBindingParameter", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(CommandParameterChanged));

    private static void CommandParameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var input = d as InputBinding;
        if (input != null)
            input.CommandParameter = e.NewValue;
    }
    public static object GetCommandBindingParameter(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(CommandBindingParameterProperty);
    }
    public static void SetCommandBindingParameter(DependencyObject o, object value)
    {
        o.SetValue(CommandBindingParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }


    private bool _parameter;
    public bool Parameter
    {
        get { return _parameter; }
        set
        {
            _parameter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Parameter");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Parameter = true;
    }

    private RelayCommand<bool> _someCommand;

    public ICommand SomeCommand
    {
        get { return _someCommand ?? (_someCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(Execute, CanExecute)); }
    }

    private bool CanExecute(bool arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    private void Execute(bool obj)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Name="Window"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    >
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="A" local:Helper.CommandBinding="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, ElementName=Window}" local:Helper.CommandBindingParameter="{Binding DataContext.Parameter, ElementName=Window}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="SomeButton" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this solution.

Use Blend 3 Interactions, i.e. Add System.Windows.Interactivity & Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll as reference into your project. I have tested the changes below. Execute method (defined in ViewModel) is called the movement textbox is keyed in.

**Modified XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    Name="Window">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                       <local:CommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Parameter}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CommandAction.CS**: Instead of Helper, use CommandAction. CommandAction is found at [this location](https://code.google.com/p/wpflib/source/browse/WPFLib/Behaviors/CommandAction.cs?r=414d1a2f06f4a336d1c6ed13e2d5a1a2b0469ab1&spec=svn11545d8f2f6059a93a4bcbc2819d19c7d422d6f5)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The CommandAction allows the user to route a FrameworkElement's routed event to a Command.
    /// For instance this makes it possible to specify--in Xaml--that right-clicking on a Border 
    /// element should execute the Application.Close command (this example may not make much sense, 
    /// but it does illustrate what's possible).
    /// 
    /// CommandParameter and CommandTarget properties are provided for consistency with the Wpf 
    /// Command pattern.
    /// 
    /// The action's IsEnabled property will be updated according to the Command's CanExecute value.
    /// 
    /// In addition a SyncOwnerIsEnabled property allows the user to specify that the owner element
    /// should be enabled/disabled whenever the action is enabled/disabled.
    /// </summary>
    public class CommandAction : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>, ICommandSource
    {
        #region Properties to Expose
        [Category("Command Properties")]
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandAction), new PropertyMetadata(
                (ICommand)null, OnCommandChanged));

        [Category("Command Properties")]
        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandAction), new PropertyMetadata());

        [Category("Command Properties")]
        public IInputElement CommandTarget
        {
            get { return (IInputElement)GetValue(CommandTargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandTargetProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CommandTarget", typeof(IInputElement), typeof(CommandAction), new PropertyMetadata());

        [Category("Command Properties")]
        public bool SyncOwnerIsEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(SyncOwnerIsEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SyncOwnerIsEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When SyncOwnerIsEnabled is true then changing CommandAction.IsEnabled will automatically
        /// update the owner (Target) IsEnabled property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SyncOwnerIsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SyncOwnerIsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(CommandAction), new PropertyMetadata());

        #endregion

        #region Command implementation

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a strong reference to the Command.CanExecuteChanged event handler. The commanding
        /// system uses a weak reference and if we don't enforce a strong reference then the event
        /// handler will be gc'ed.
        /// </summary>
        private EventHandler CanExecuteChangedHandler;

        private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var action = (CommandAction)d;
            action.OnCommandChanged((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
        }

        private void OnCommandChanged(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
        {
            if (oldCommand != null)
                UnhookCommand(oldCommand);
            if (newCommand != null)
                HookCommand(newCommand);
        }

        private void UnhookCommand(ICommand command)
        {
            command.CanExecuteChanged -= CanExecuteChangedHandler;
            UpdateCanExecute();
        }

        private void HookCommand(ICommand command)
        {
            // Save a strong reference to the Command.CanExecuteChanged event handler. The commanding
            // system uses a weak reference and if we don't save a strong reference then the event
            // handler will be gc'ed.
            CanExecuteChangedHandler = new EventHandler(OnCanExecuteChanged);
            command.CanExecuteChanged += CanExecuteChangedHandler;
            UpdateCanExecute();
        }

        private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateCanExecute();
        }

        private void UpdateCanExecute()
        {
            if (Command != null)
            {
                RoutedCommand command = Command as RoutedCommand;
                if (command != null)
                    IsEnabled = command.CanExecute(CommandParameter, CommandTarget);
                else
                    IsEnabled = Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter);
                if (Target != null && SyncOwnerIsEnabled)
                    Target.IsEnabled = IsEnabled;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        protected override void Invoke(object o)
        {
            if (Command != null)
            {
                var command = Command as RoutedCommand;
                if (command != null)
                    command.Execute(CommandParameter, CommandTarget);
                else
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot: if System.Windows.Interactivity & Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll are missing in your environment, please install blend. Blend is very easy to isntall and Installation doesn't take much time.

[image: Screenshot]